# How to make a link to a sprite file itself created by Compass in a background: url() property?

Tags: css, compass-sass, compass

I have a sprite file created by Compass. And there is an image in that sprite file. And I have an element with a `background: url()` property. Is there some special helpers in Compass that allow to reference the sprite file in `url()`?

Here is an example:

```
        a {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #FFF;
        }
        a:before {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            height: 20px;
            width: 24px;
            left: 9px;
            top: 18px;
            background: url("HOW TO GET SPRITE FILE HERE?") no-repeat scroll -55px 0 transparent;
        }
```

Comment: Everything you should know about using Compass sprites is described in [this tutorial](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are generating your sprite, but you should be able to use `sprite-url($map)` to get the url. There are a couple of other ways to handle it though depending on how you generated the sprite. Here is a link to the documentation for sprite-url and if you scroll up on the page, it will give you the other ways that you can generate the sprite and output the necessary url: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/#sprite-url

Comment: Ok, what does `$map` variable mean? How to get it in my `.scss` file? That tutorial you gave a link to doesn't answer this question.

Comment: Sprite is generated itself. I use `compass watch .` and it generates a sprite every time I save my `.scss` file.

Comment: @Green Somewhere you most likely have a line calling  `sprite-map` that generates the sprite. The return value of that is what you would want to pass in as `$map`.